# K is the least positive integer divisible by all positive integers less than or equal to 10. Find the total number of factors of K?

Tags: gre-exam

the answer is 46. I am not able to figure out how to arrive at that answer

Comment: Hint:  10 is a bit large, try it for a smaller number.  Like $3$ or $5$.  For small numbers you should be able to write everything out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually you *can't* arrive at the answer, because the answer should be 48.

The long way is to list all factors of 2520, viz. 1 through 10, 12,14,15, ... 2520

but the theory of numbers says that if you break them up into prime factors, viz $2^3 \cdot3^2 \cdot 5^1 \cdot 7^1$,

add 1 to each of the indices and multiply them out, you get the answer: $4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot2 = 48$

Look [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factors+of+2520) to see all 48 factors

*NOTE*

The term *proper* factor should have been used in the question to get the answer of 46, but if you have been taught to exclude 1 & the number  anyway, just subtract 2 from the number theory computation.

Comment: I suspect they may be looking for proper factors only (excluding $1$ and $K$), in which case subtracting $2$ from your answer gives the desired one.

Comment: I suppose so, but shouldn't they then mention it ?

Comment: It may be an explicit part of the text's definition of "factor" (though that seems like a bad idea to me).

Comment: Thanks, I have added a note on the issue in the answer.

Comment: You're welcome !

Comment: Hi. Can u explain how u got 2520?

Comment: LCM of {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

Answer (score 0):

The least positive integer divisible by $1,2,3,4$ is $4\cdot 3 = 12$. Note that it is *not* $2\cdot 3\cdot 4 = 24$ - we don't need to include the $2$, because any integer that is divisible by $4$ is also divisible by $2$.

Now you need to generalize that idea to $1,2,\cdots,10$.

Comment: Ok so I get: 9, 8, 7, 5 (using divisibility rules). And 9*8*7*5= 2520. How do I proceed after that? Thank you for the help